# Overriding an anonymous class's methods in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-class

In below example (in the commented block) I'm trying to override `jump()` method of an anonymous class, however getting compilation error. Can someone help me understand what's wrong here?

```java
class Animal {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Inside bark");
    }

    public void jump() {
        System.out.println("Inside jump");
    }
}

public class AnonymousClassExample001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal() {
            public void bark() {
                System.out.println("Subclass bark");
            }
        }; /* {
            public void jump() {
                System.out.println("Subclass jump");
            }
        };*/

        /**
        * Question is: Why can't we override by extending an anonymous class
        * as attempted (and commented) above?
        * */
        animal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        animal.jump(); // Trying to print "Subclass jump", by overriding (the subclass of Animal) above
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Here's the compilation error I'm getting in IDE - `';' expected`.

And from the comments, it seems some folks are not getting my question. With the above example, I wanted to understand **whether we can override an anonymous class's methods or not?**.

Again, the main motive is to see (and understand) why Java compiler allowed to create an anonymous class by starting a `{}` block followed by `new Animal()`, and didn't allow the same behaviour further (chaining of `{}` blocks to allow creation of further subclasses)

[image]

Comment: Move it up next to the other method.

Comment: Do you always want `animal.jump()` to print `Subclass jump`?

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes, however that's not the main motive. Main motive is to see (and understand) why Java compiler allowed to create an anonymous class by starting a `{}` block followed by `new Animal() `, and didn't allow the same behaviour further (chaining of `{}` blocks to allow creation of further subclasses)

Comment: It's because the syntax allows anonymous class definitions to follow a constructor within the bounds of `{` and `}`. The `;` signals the end of the constructor. No more constructor syntax allowed after `;`. After the `;`, there must be a new statement. This chaining you refer to does not exist in the fashion you desire.

Comment: If you simply delete line 19, then you'll be good to go. The language is composable but it wouldn't be if what you show were allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't end and restart the block, override both methods in one block, same as you would in a regular subclass:

```java
class AnonymousClassExample001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal() {
            @Override
            public void bark() {
                System.out.println("Subclass bark");
            }
            @Override
            public void jump() {
                System.out.println("Subclass jump");
            }
        };

        animal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        animal.jump(); // Subclass jump
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Updates to the question says you're trying to subclass an anonymous class, e.g. you're trying to do this:

```java
class AnonymousClassExample001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal barkingAnimal = new Animal() {
            @Override
            public void bark() {
                System.out.println("Subclass bark");
            }
        };
        Animal jumpingAnimal = <subclass barkingAnimal> { // Can't be done
            @Override
            public void jump() {
                System.out.println("Subclass jump");
            }
        };

        barkingAnimal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        barkingAnimal.jump(); // Inside jump

        jumpingAnimal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        jumpingAnimal.jump(); // Subclass jump
    }
}
```

You can't do that, because the *unnamed* anonymous class cannot be identified as the base class. You can however do it using **local classes**, which are like named anonymous classes, as contradictory as that sounds:

```java
class AnonymousClassExample001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class BarkingAnimal extends Animal {
            @Override
            public void bark() {
                System.out.println("Subclass bark");
            }
        };
        class JumpingAnimal extends BarkingAnimal {
            @Override
            public void jump() {
                System.out.println("Subclass jump");
            }
        };
        Animal barkingAnimal = new BarkingAnimal();
        Animal jumpingAnimal = new JumpingAnimal();

        barkingAnimal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        barkingAnimal.jump(); // Inside jump

        jumpingAnimal.bark(); // Subclass bark
        jumpingAnimal.jump(); // Subclass jump
    }
}
```

Alternatively, `jumpingAnimal` could also be done using anonymous class syntax, instead of local class syntax.

Comment: Maybe you got my question wrong, with the added example I wanted to ask **Can we override an anonymous class's methods?**.

Comment: @AadityaSharma No, because the anonymous class is ... well, anonymous, i.e. it has no name, so you cannot refer to it to subclass it again. --- Besides, that's not what the code in the question is doing, it's just attempting to overriding both methods.

Comment: Well, with the question "title + body" I tried to make it clear that I'm trying to extend methods of an anonymous class. Please feel free to suggest an edit if you want.

Comment: @AadityaSharma What I *think* you want to ask is "how do you override two methods *with* an anonymous class?" You don't ever override methods *of* an anonymous class. You instead override a Class's methods *with* an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
public class AnonymousClassExample001 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal = new Animal() {
        public void bark() {
            System.out.println("Subclass bark");
        }

        public void jump() {
            System.out.println("Subclass jump");

        }
    };
    /**
     * Question is: Why can't we override by extending an anonymous class
     * as attempted (and commented) above?
     * */
    animal.bark(); // Subclass bark
    animal.jump(); // Trying to print "Subclass jump", by overriding (the subclass of Animal) above
}
}
```